# Add free shipping label to magento product pages with price over a certain amount?

Tags: magento, label, magento-1.6, php

I would like to add a "Free Shipping" label somewhere on my Magento product pages. That code is pretty simple:

```
<?php echo $this->__('FREE SHIPPING') ?>
```

The problem is, I only offer free shipping on products costing over $199.

How can I set up an if statement to only display this label if price is over $199?

Thanks for your help (I'm on Magento v1.6.1 by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try do something like this:

```
// somewhere on product page, e.g. view.phtml
<?php if ($_product->getPrice() > 199) :
//if you don't have direct access to $_product variable from your template or to $this->getProduct() method of block template belongs to, try using registry,e.g.
//if (Mage::registry('current_product')->getPrice() > 199):
    echo $this->__('FREE SHIPPING');
endif; ?>
```

Hope it will help.